# Druid not storing to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, druid

I am trying to push the data to AWS S3. I had user the example in (http://druid.io/docs/0.7.0/Tutorial:-The-Druid-Cluster.html) but modified the common.runtime.properties as below

```
druid.storage.type=s3
druid.s3.accessKey=AKIAJWTETHZDEQLHQ7AQ
druid.s3.secretKey=tcTtvGXcqLmmMbo2hRunzlSA1P2X0O0bjVf537Nt
druid.storage.bucket=testfeed
druid.storage.baseKey=sample
```

Below is the logs for realtime node

> 2015-03-02T15:03:44,809 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.query.QueryConfig] from
>   props[druid.query.] as [io.druid.query.QueryConfig@2edcd9d]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,843 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.query.search.search.SearchQueryConfig]
>   from props[druid.query.search.] as
>   [io.druid.query.search.search.SearchQueryConfig@7939de8b]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,861 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryConfig] from
>   props[druid.query.groupBy.] as
>   [io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryConfig@bea8209]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,874 INFO [main]
>   org.skife.config.ConfigurationObjectFactory - Assigning value
>   [100000000] for [druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes] on
>   [io.druid.query.DruidProcessingConfig#intermediateComputeSizeBytes()]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,878 INFO [main]
>   org.skife.config.ConfigurationObjectFactory - Assigning value [2] for
>   [druid.processing.numThreads] on
>   [io.druid.query.DruidProcessingConfig#getNumThreads()]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,878 INFO [main]
>   org.skife.config.ConfigurationObjectFactory - Using method itself for
>   [${base_path}.columnCache.sizeBytes] on
>   [io.druid.query.DruidProcessingConfig#columnCacheSizeBytes()]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,880 INFO [main]
>   org.skife.config.ConfigurationObjectFactory - Assigning default value
>   [processing-%s] for [${base_path}.formatString] on
>   [com.metamx.common.concurrent.ExecutorServiceConfig#getFormatString()]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,956 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.query.topn.TopNQueryConfig] from
>   props[druid.query.topN.] as
>   [io.druid.query.topn.TopNQueryConfig@276503c4]
>   **2015-03-02T15:03:44,960 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator
>   - Loaded class[class io.druid.segment.loading.LocalDataSegmentPusherConfig] from
>   props[druid.storage.] as
>   [io.druid.segment.loading.LocalDataSegmentPusherConfig@360548eb]**
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,967 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.client.DruidServerConfig] from
>   props[druid.server.] as [io.druid.client.DruidServerConfig@75ba7964]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,971 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class
>   io.druid.server.initialization.BatchDataSegmentAnnouncerConfig] from
>   props[druid.announcer.] as
>   [io.druid.server.initialization.BatchDataSegmentAnnouncerConfig@1ff2a544]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,984 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.server.initialization.ZkPathsConfig] from
>   props[druid.zk.paths.] as
>   [io.druid.server.initialization.ZkPathsConfig@58d3f4be]
>   2015-03-02T15:03:44,990 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator -
>   Loaded class[class io.druid.curator.CuratorConfig] from
>   props[druid.zk.service.] as [io.druid.curator.CuratorConfig@5fd11499]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. I had missed the s3 extension in common.runtime.properties. Once that was added data started getting pushed to s3.

Comment: Can you post a snippet illustrating what that looks like?

Comment: Actually i didnt implement any code. Was following the example mentioned above.

Comment: @user766353 here's the line to add the s3 extension: `druid.extensions.coordinates=["io.druid.extensions:druid-s3-extensions:0.6.173"]` I'm running druid version 0.6.173, make sure you change that to your version.